# Proving Events belong to a tail sigma field

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm really confused about tail sigma fields and how to prove that a set is or is not a tail event (belongs to the tail sigma field).

I was wondering if anyone has seen examples of proving that a set is a tail sigma field. I am trying to prove that $A= \{\inf_{k \ge 1}Y_k \le 1\}$ is in the tail sigma field $\mathscr T(Y_k: K\ge 1)$ where $Y_k,k\ge 1$ are $[0,\infty)$ valued random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, we need to show that $A=\{\inf_{k≥1}Y_k=1\}$ is independent of $\{\inf_{k≥m}Y_k=1\}$ for arbitrary $m$

Essentially, we need to show that it doesn't matter if we "skip" a finite number of $k's$.

now, consider the set $Y_k=${$1,2,2,2,2,2,2,...$}, $inf_{k≥1}Y_k=1$

But, for any $m$, $\inf_{k≥m}Y_k=2$ Hence, the event $\{inf_{k≥1}Y_k=1\}$ depends on $Y_1$. Therefore, it is not in the tail sigma field.

An example where an event *is* in $\mathcal T$ is: $B=\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ converges $\}$

Clearly, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ converges only if $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} X_n$ converges $\forall m$.

Thus, $B\in \mathcal T$.

Comment: So, this works for any set? For example I am trying to use your method to find whether  $B= \{ \liminf_{k \to \infty} Y_k < \infty \}$ is in the tail sigma field, so I have to show that B is independent of  $\{ \liminf_{m \to \infty} Y_m < \infty \}$ for $m>k$ arbitrary ?

Comment: yes, precisely. Be careful with $\liminf$ though, because it is different than $\inf$ Think of it as just $\lim$

Comment: what do you mean by that ? as in I should show that B is independent of $\lim_{n \to \infty} ( \inf_{m>k>n} Y_k$ ?

Comment: Yes, $\liminf$ is in the tail sigma field. Because, $\liminf$ is the union over all intersections of $A_ks$ Therefore, if something is in $\liminf A_k, k≥1$ it is in  $\liminf A_k, k≥m$

Comment: out of curiousity, does your answer change at all if you use my definition for A? As I define A to be less than or equal to 1, but you choose it to be =1 ?

Comment: consider the set: {.5,1.01,1.01,1.01,1.01,1.01,...} same thing. look at when $k≥1$ and when $k≥2$ so, it doesn't depend on the long run behavior of the sequence. Essentially, a finite set of values can screw things up.